# Thread.start() doesn't initialize run()

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have some problems with my code. For some reason my thread.start() doesn't activate my run() method. In pure desperation I have simply replaced my code in run() with a printing function, but nothing is being printed. Can someone help me by explaining what is wrong in my code?

```
public class Screen extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    Thread thread = new Thread();

    Frame frame;

    public Screen(Frame frame){
        this.frame = frame;
        frame.setSize(horizontal * 25 + 24 , (vertical) * 25 + 48);
        this.frame.addKeyListener(new KeyHandler(this));
        thread.start();
    }
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Boom");
    }
}
```

I got a lot of stuff in between and under this code, but this is the only part essential to the thread and frame.

Comment: when you create a Thread. which thread? It doesnt have any reference to tie back to your class. it should be new Thread(this) isnt it?

Comment: when you implement thread using Runnable u need to pass object of that class to thread.... here do the following.... **new Thread(this)**

Comment: Btw, it is considered a bad pattern to fork a thread in an object constructor.  This causes a leak of `this` to the other thread before the object is fully constructed.  It is a better pattern to add a `screen.start()`  method which calls `thread.start()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must pass the `Thread` a `Runnable`. Since `thread` is an instance variable and the class implements `Runnable` I guess you want to do this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(this);
```

But be careful when calling overridable methods from a constructor and be more careful if these methods are called by a separate thread that runs the code in parralel to the constructor initialization. It might run while the constructor still initializes the object. Think about what will happen if you subclass `Screen`, override the `run` method and the run method accesses properties of the superclass `Screen` while it is initializing.

Also see [What's wrong with overridable method calls in constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors)

Comment: @user2855788 I added another hint.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your thread doesn't know about the run method. You can do it by changing

```
Thread thread = new Thread();
```

to

```
Thread thread = new Thread(this);
```

because your class is an instance of Runnable.

p.s. try to avoid messing with threads and Swing. Use SwingWorkers if you really have to.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea to combine the two? :)

Comment: @Anne-Katrine If you don't pay attention, you may end up freezing your UI by blocking EDT

Answer (score 0):

Thread needs a `Runnable` instance, which has `run()` method to call. But you are not providing `Runnable` instance to `Thread`.

Do `Thread t = new Thread(this);`

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a simple thread.

```
Thread thread = new Thread();
```

It does call `run()` method but of class `Thread` and not your Screen class runnable implementation.

You can do

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Screen());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions:
1) Using the override `run` method in your class

```
Thread thread = new Thread(this);
```

2) Using `new Runnable`

```
Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // your code

        }
    });
```